# Drawing top border on a semi-transparent shape on Android

Tags: android, background, border, line, transparent

I want to set the background of my layout to semi-transparent color with top border (not transparent) on it. I tried to achieve this. Currently my drawable file looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000FF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#7F000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But in this xml the semi-transparent shape goes on the non-transparent shape, so in the result it isn't semi-transparent at all. Can you please help me to get the background I want?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting a fixed size for the blue opaque rectangle using the <size> tag inside the <shape>, with a 5dp height?

Comment: I just tried it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the web and trying to find the right solution, finally I've got the answer from the guys in the chat. The solution is to create one more `layout` on top of the first one and for example give it a height of `10dp` and the width of `match_parent`.

---

*Here is the working example:*

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Border"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.64"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="InefficientWeight" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.64"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/example"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**main_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FF990000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#55000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFFF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Transparent Views</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="example">Content &#8230;</string>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>

</resources>
```

---

Hope it will be helpful for someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:left="-5dp" android:bottom="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/borderColor" />
            <solid android:color="@color/backgroundColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```